# How can I plot a cumulative distribution function (CDF) for binned data?

Tags: r, plot, ecdf

I've got discrete data which i presented in ranges
for example

```
         Marks Freq cumFreq 
1  (37.9,43.1]    4       4    
2  (43.1,48.2]   16      20   
3  (48.2,53.3]   76      96
```

i need to plot the cmf for this data, I know that there is

```
plot(ecdf(x))
```

but i don't what to add for it to have what I need.

Comment: What exactly do you want this plot to look like? It is very unclear what your desired output is.

Comment: I need to plot the cdf for this classed data,
theorical, we take the centre of each class and draw the cdf just as we have discrete values which are the centres each has the frequency of its interval.
my problem is i dont know how take centre of this classes.

i hope i was clear.

Comment: So are you saying that your "class" is the "Marks" column? And that's a character column? You don't have the raw data that was used to create the value? And that you want to assume that all the mass for each group lines at the center of the range? And by `cdf`, you mean you want a stepwise function that starts at 0 and increases to 1 for the last value, increasing at each unique range?

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few options:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

## Fake data
set.seed(2)
dat = data.frame(score=c(rnorm(130,40,10), rnorm(130,80,5)))
```

Here's how to plot the ECDF if you have the raw data:

```
# Base graphics
plot(ecdf(dat$score))

# ggplot2
ggplot(dat, aes(score)) +
  stat_ecdf(aes(group=1), geom="step")
```

Here's one way to plot the ECDF if you have only summary data:

First, let's group the data into bins, similar to what you have in your question. We use the `cut` function to create the bins and then create a new `pct` column to calculate each bins fraction of the total number of scores. We use the `dplyr` chaining operator (`%>%`) to do it all in one "chain" of functions.

```
dat.binned = dat %>% count(Marks=cut(score,seq(0,100,5))) %>%
         mutate(pct = n/sum(n))
```

Now we can plot it. `cumsum(pct)` calculates the cumulative percentages (like `cumFreq` in your question). `geom_step` creates step plot with these cumulative percentages.

```
ggplot(dat.binned, aes(Marks, cumsum(pct))) +
  geom_step(aes(group=1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format())
```

Here's what the plots look like:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: See updated answer. Let me know if you'd like additional clarification.

Comment: You should use linear interpolation because you are using binned data? The interpolation accounts for the uncertainty to where the points lie within each class (uniform distributed within the class). See my answer below... But thanks for the ggplot version. Looks nice :-)

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(2)
dat = data.frame(score = c(rnorm(130,40,10), rnorm(130,80,5)))
dat.binned = dat %>% count(Marks = cut(score,seq(0,100,5))) %>%
         mutate(pct = n/sum(n))
ggplot(data = dat.binned, mapping = aes(Marks, cumsum(pct))) +  
  geom_line(aes(group = 1)) + 
  geom_point(data = dat.binned, size = 0.1, color = "blue") +
  labs(x = "Frequency(Hz)", y = "Axis") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

[image]